# Ordenação decrescente!

Tags: asp.net

Em minha página cshtml tenho um foreach que lê essas informações do banco e plota na tela em forma de checkbox, estou tentando ordenar ou reverter em forma decrescente na tela, mas não estou conseguindo, segue as informações abaixo dos dados da tabela:

1   Quantidade de Água

2   Quantidade de Espuma

3   Extintor de incêndio

4   Areia/Terra

5   Pública

6   Particular

7   Aceiro
8   Uso de aeronave

9   Abafador

11  Retirada de Material

Queria fazer no meu razor ler do 11 ao 1 pra aparecer na tela, alguém poderia me dar um help, segue o código:

```js
@using SDO.Domain.Entities
@model List<OcorrenciaIncendioModoExtincao>
@{
    var modo1 = Model.FirstOrDefault(m => m.ModoExtincaoId == 1);
    var modo2 = Model.FirstOrDefault(m => m.ModoExtincaoId == 2);
    var modo5 = Model.FirstOrDefault(m => m.ModoExtincaoId == 5);
    var modo6 = Model.FirstOrDefault(m => m.ModoExtincaoId == 6);
}
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">Modo Extinção</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="input-container panel-body" name="FormModoExtincao">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            @foreach (var modo in ViewBag.ModoExtincao as List<ModoExtincao> )
            {
                if (modo.Id == 5)
                {
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        
                    </div>
                }
                <div class="col-sm-3" name="modo-@modo.Id">
                    <p>
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox"
                                   classname="ModosExtincao"
                                   name="ModoExtincaoId"
                                   id="@modo.Id"
                                   value="@modo.Id"
                                   @(modo.Dependencia.HasValue ? "data-dep=" + modo.Dependencia.Value + " ignore" : "data-dep=0")
                                   @(Model.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ModoExtincaoId == modo.Id) != null ? "checked" : "")
                                   @(modo.Dependencia.HasValue && Model.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ModoExtincaoId == modo.Dependencia) != null && ((modo.Id == 5 || modo.Id == 2) && Model.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ModoExtincaoId == modo.Dependencia).QtdConsumidaPublica > 0) ? "checked" : "" )
                                   @(modo.Dependencia.HasValue && Model.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ModoExtincaoId == modo.Dependencia) != null && (modo.Id == 6 && Model.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ModoExtincaoId == modo.Dependencia).QtdConsumidaParticular > 0) ? "checked" : "" ) />

                            @modo.Descricao
                        </label>
                        @if (modo.Id == 2 || modo.Id == 5 || modo.Id == 6) //ESPUMA, PUBLICA, PARTICULAR
                        {
                        <div class="complemento" data-dep="@modo.Id">
                            <span>@(modo.Id == 2 ? "Quantidade consumida (Litros)" : "Quantidade consumida (m³)")</span>
                            <div>
                                <input type="number"
                                       classname="ModosExtincao"
                                       class="form-control form-control-80"
                                       name="QtdConsumida-@modo.Id"
                                       data-dep="@modo.Id"
                                       belongs-to="@(modo.Dependencia.HasValue ? modo.Dependencia : modo.Id)"
                                       searchfor="ModoExtincaoId"
                                       max="99999"
                                       maxlength="5"
                                       value="@((modo2 != null && modo.Id == 2 && modo2.QtdConsumidaEspuma != null)
                                                     ? modo2.QtdConsumidaEspuma.ToString()
                                                            : (modo1 != null && modo.Id == 5 && modo1.QtdConsumidaPublica != null )
                                                            ? modo1.QtdConsumidaPublica.ToString()
                                                                : (modo1 != null && modo.Id == 6 && modo1.QtdConsumidaParticular != null)
                                                                    ? modo1.QtdConsumidaParticular.ToString()
                                                                    : "")" />
                            </div>
                            @if (modo.Id == 6)
                            {
                                var ed = Model.FirstOrDefault(m => m.ModoExtincaoId == modo.Dependencia);
                                <div>
                                    <span>Do próprio imóvel?</span>
                                    <label><input type="radio" name="ProprioImovel" value="1" @(ed != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(ed.EnderecoOutraEdificacao) ? "checked" : "" ) />Sim</label>
                                    <label><input type="radio" name="ProprioImovel" value="0" @(ed != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ed.EnderecoOutraEdificacao) ? "checked" : "" ) />Não</label>
                                    <div class="complemento">
                                        <span>Endereço da edificação da qual usou a água: </span>
                                        <input type="text"
                                               classname="ModosExtincao"
                                               class="form-control"
                                               belongs-to="@modo.Dependencia"
                                               searchfor="ModoExtincaoId"
                                               maxlength="80"
                                               name="EnderecoOutraEdificacao"
                                               value="@(ed != null ? ed.EnderecoOutraEdificacao : "" )" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            }
                        </div>
                        }
                    </p>&nbsp;
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Obrigado.

Comment: Você quer ordenar de forma decrescente pelo campo `ModoExtincaoId`?

Comment: Seria na variável modo do foreach, todos os ids passa um a um pelo modo

Comment: Mas essa sua variável é uma lista de objeto do tipo `ModoExtincao`, você gostaria de ordenar de forma decrescente a partir de qual campo dessa classe? Por exemplo, pelo identificador, pelo nome, pela descrição. Me diga o nome do campo por favor

Comment: Ah ok, então nunca irei conseguir ordenar, pois a variável modo seria uma lista de objeto!

Comment: Consegue sim, mas eu quero saber por qual campo você gostaria de ordenar rsrs. Me fala o nome do atributo que você quer ordenar.

Comment: Na classe ModoExtincao tenho os campos Id, Descricao e Dependencia, pode ser ordenação por id

Comment: Ve se isso te ajuda. Ele muda a ordem dos elementos html, o último fica em primeiro e assim por diante. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/350191/ordenar-cadastros-adicionados-recentemente-dinamicamente/350203#350203

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme discutido nos comentários, você gostaria de ordenar de forma decrescente pelo identificador dos seus objetos. Para isso, altere a linha do seu `foreach` conforme exemplo abaixo, assim iremos realizar a ordenação via `Linq`:

```
@foreach (var modo in (ViewBag.ModoExtincao as List<ModoExtincao>).OrderByDescending(o => o.Id))
{
    //Aqui continua o fluxo já existente...
}
```

Caso queira adicionar mais campos na ordenação, utilize o método `ThenByDescending` para ordenação decrescente e `ThenBy` para ordenação crescente. Pode-se utilizar quantas vezes for preciso:

```
@foreach (var modo in (ViewBag.ModoExtincao as List<ModoExtincao>).OrderByDescending(o => o.Id).ThenByDescending(o => o.Descricao).ThenByDescending(o.Dependencia))
{
    //Aqui continua o fluxo já existente...
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Pedro Paulo pelo força e a todos que me ajudaram.

Comment: Tamo junto bro!